# How to run a single command multiple times while changing one word in the command each time it is run?

Tags: command-line, grep

I've got a command like this:

```
grep word1 file.txt | grep word2 | grep word3
```

I want to be able to run this entire command multiple times while changing the value of "word1" each time.  I have a file called insert.txt that contains a list of words I'd like to replace "word1" with each time it is run.

How would I accomplish something like this?

Comment: What is your final goal? What about `grep word2 | grep word3` ?

Comment: grep word2 | grep word3 will not change.  I guess to simplify the question, how would you do it for just: grep word1 file.txt

Comment: Do you want the patterns from insert.txt be grepped all at once or do you want to grep the first, then run teh remaining greps and then second pattern..third ..?

Comment: I'd like it to grep using the first line in insert.txt, then grep again using the second line in insert.txt, etc, etc until it finishes running for all the lines in insert.txt

Comment: So you want to grep word 1 from file, then grep word2 from file , and then grep word 3 from file, is that right ? Or do you wanna get a string with word 1 in it, then get out word 2 from that string , and then word 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this if you want to take each line **at a time** from the file `insert.txt` as pattern to search in `file.txt`, this will output only the lines from `file.txt` that matches the line in consideration from `insert.txt`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r word1; do
       grep -- "$word1" file.txt | grep "word2" | grep "word3"
done < insert.txt
```

Here `--` is given to indicate the end of `grep`'s options, otherwise the patterns staring with `-` will not work.

On the other hand, run the following if you want to use all the lines of `insert.txt` as pattern for searching in `file.txt` **at once**, this will match all the lines of `file.txt` that matches any of the lines of `insert.txt`:

```
grep -Ff insert.txt file.txt | grep "word2" | grep "word3"
```

Comment: Hey Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In the first example you probably want `--` in case word1 starts with a hyphen.

Comment: @kojiro: Right..edited..